# How can I access the in-game console?

Tags: diep.io

I have some commands that I'd like to type in the console. How can I access the console so I am able to do this?

Here's an example of one of the commands I want to run:

```
ren_replace_color 1 0xFEFEFA
```

Comment: These answers could easily be condensed into a single answer that you can accept... you can't accept multiple answers so posting three separate answers is kind of wonky

Comment: The keybind answer makes the most sense because the other two need to have the console open.

Comment: yeah, but you could have it be the first part of your answer, then mention the others as alternative solutions. Having multiple answers to one question (especially your *own* questions) is a bit odd... having one condensed, high-quality answer is much better than a bunch of incomplete answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Keyboard

**Short answer:** Press your home key or its replacement.

**Long answer:** You can access the console by using a key bind. On most keyboards with a numpad you can press <kbd>Home</kbd> while on you might have to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> on keyboards missing the numpad (most laptops)

---

Here are some more technical solutions, although the keyboard answer is the easiest.

## Simulating Keypresses

You can use the `keyDown` function to simulate a home keypress with the event's key code.

The key bind that works on [the first answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302981/145171) will work here as well, but you have to fill in the key codes.

Paste this command into the Inspect Element console and run it:

```
input.keyDown(38);
```

`38` is the key code for <kbd>Home</kbd> so the console will open.

You cannot use the key codes for <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> because they are converted to `38` automatically when pressed together.

## Toggle Command

You can use a command in the Inspect Element console to show the console:

```
input.execute("con_toggle");
```

If the console is already visible, then it will hide.

Since this itself is a console command, if you manage to find the console and run the below command (with the execute function stripped off), then the console will hide there as well.

```
con_toggle
```

Comment: Please keep your answer altogether instead of separating them out across different answers. You can use three dashes (`---`) to create a horizontal break in order to separate multiple distinct points if you wish (as I have done when combining your answer).

Comment: @Robotnik No, I'm splitting it into 2.

Comment: Why do you want to split it into 2?

Comment: @54D The other 2 answers are more technical and I'm sure the keyboard answer will help the most. But you can't downvote just because it's 2 answers

Comment: I'm pretty sure everyone can downvote because it's 2 answers. I don't. Even if the other two answers are more technical, that does not mean they should be separated from the third. You should place the answer that might help the most people at the front of your answer followed by the answers that you consider less helpful, instead of splitting them into two. Not only does this make you look like you are trying to gain 2 upvotes from answering the question "once", but also should everyone follow your practice, it makes this site very cluttered and disorganized.

Comment: We're just trying to keep site quality high, and information organized. Please don't take it personally. I get you're excited about this game. But look at it from our side; we just have a user who's posting lots of questions and answers. Lots of it isn't very good, or isn't really organized the way we want. That makes more work for us.